# Downloading ImageURL from Firebase

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, error-handling, nsurlconnection

I have a swift project that is storing data and an image in Firebase.I am looking to pass an image which loads successfully in my uitableview from the tableviewcell to another uiviewcontroller.

I am using the following function and then calling that function in viewdidload:

```
func downloadImg() {
    let url = URL(string: (post?.imageUrl)!)
    if let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url!) {
        mainImage.image = UIImage(data: data)
    } else {
        mainImage.image = nil
    }
}
```

Here is a copy of JSON produced when I load my tableview

```
SNAP: Snap (kdjfglskfj39fh) {
detailedDescription = "little flat";
imageUrl = "gs://frelocate.appspot.com/main-image/house3.jpeg";
location = Paris;
street = "Paris road";
title = "1 bed flat";
value = "\U00a31000000";
}
```

This works some of the time but the rest of the the time my else statement is called and the image is set to nil. I am also getting the error "NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1002".

I hope this is enough information, I am a new, hobby coder so Im not the best on stackoverflow:/

Thank you for any help you may be able to give me.

Comment: can you provide some json sample of your image data in firebase?

Comment: This link may help: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698788/xcode-9-ios-11-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-fails

Comment: Firebase has a great library that can handle downloading images, so why not use that? Check it out here: https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/download-files#downloading_images_with_firebaseui