# Convert images from URL returns NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022

Tags: ios, swift, swift4

I'm trying to solve this issue:
I know, is very documented

[NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47865216/nsurlconnection-finished-with-error-code-1022)

[xCode 9 - iOS 11: NSURLConnection - sendAsynchronousRequest fails](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44698788/xcode-9-ios-11-nsurlconnection-sendasynchronousrequest-fails?rq=1)

Well, for some reason, that's not resolve my problem.

I already in my **info.plist** file:

```
<key>NSAppTransportSecurity</key>
    <dict>
        <key>NSAllowsArbitraryLoads</key>
        <true/>
    </dict>
```

All the request, are ok, but, when I try to parse a `string base64` to an image, I get the error:

> NSURLConnection finished with error - code -1022

That happens exact in this moment:

```
let image = datasource[i].File!.base64ToImage()
let imageView = UIImageView(image: image)
```

The message is displayed exactly when I try to convert to `UIImageView`.

also, I'm using this extension:

```
func base64ToImage() -> UIImage? {
        if let url = URL(string: self),let data = try? Data(contentsOf: url),let image = UIImage(data: data) {
            return image
        }
        return nil
    }
```

The datasource contains the correct info for all the keys (also, are tested).

Someone has an idea about how to solve it?

Comment: Don't use `Data(contentsOf: url)`, that's blocking your thread, and then potentially the UI. What about using `URLSession` (async), and maybe get more info on the issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
var base64String: NSString!
let myImage = UIImage(named:"image.png")
let imageData = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(myImage, 0.9)
base64String = imageData!.base64EncodedString(options: NSData.Base64EncodingOptions.endLineWithLineFeed) as NSString!
print(base64String)
Base64String to Data

let thumbnail1Data =  Data(base64Encoded: base64String as String, options: NSData.Base64DecodingOptions()
imageView?.image = UIImage(data: thumbnail1Data as Data)
```